# cant create a new Collection in Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I can't create a new Collection in Firebase. I created a collection called User to store Profildata which works, but now I need another to store something else.

Everything is working but it don't creates the collection on backend.

And I nearly used the same code which I used for the first collection.

```
function Waffen(){

  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);
  const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);

  const [Hersteller, setHersteller] = useState(['Baretta', 
  'Walther']);
  const [Modell, setModell] = useState();
  const [Kaliber, setKaliber] = useState();
  const history = useHistory("");
  const [data] = useState({loading: false,});
  const { loading } = data;
  
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    await setDoc(doc(db, 'Waffen' ,auth.currentUser.uid),  
    
    { Hersteller: Hersteller, Modell: Modell, Kaliber: Kaliber 
    });
  
      setOpen(false)
      history.replace("/Profil");
    }; 
  




 return (
    <div >
      <Button onClick={handleOpen}>Meine Waffen</Button>
        <Modal 
          open={open}
          onClose={handleClose}>
          <Box sx={style} >
            <form  >

        <Grid
         container
         justifyContent="center"
         alignItems="center"
         spacing={2}
        >     
         
         <Autocomplete
            disablePortal
            id="combo-box-demo"
            options={Hersteller}
            sx={{ width: 300 }}
            renderInput={(params) =>  

      <TextField {...params}  label='Hersteller'
          value={Hersteller}  onChange={event => 
          setHersteller(event.target.value)}
      />}
      />
          

          <Grid item>
             <TextField sx={{ width: 300}} variant="outlined" 
               color="secondary" label="Modell" type="text"
               name="Modell" value={Modell} onChange={event => 
               setModell(event.target.value)}>
             </TextField>
          </Grid>

          <Grid item >
              <TextField sx={{ width: 300}} variant="outlined" 
               color="secondary" label="Kaliber" type="text"
               name="Kaliber" value={Kaliber} onChange={event => 
               setKaliber(event.target.value)}>
              </TextField>
          </Grid>
          
           <Grid item>
              <button onSubmit={handleSubmit} 
                  className="AnmeldenButton" >
                  {loading ? "Bearbeitet ..." : "Speichern"}
              </button>
          </Grid>

        </Grid>

           </form>
         </Box>
      </Modal>
    </div>

  ) ;
  }

  export default Waffen;
```

Comment: Please pay attention to terminology, as it will help you get help around here. I think what you refer to as "database" is a collection in Firestore. Can you verify that is indeed the case, and if so, update it in your question (there's an edit link right under it)?

Comment: Thanks I edit it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger, so I recommend trying to troubleshoot yourself and posting the results. For example, if you simplify the writing to `setDoc(doc(db, 'Waffen' ,auth.currentUser.uid),  { tesst: true })` (so writing a simple hardcoded value), does it work? If not, set a breakpoint on the first line of code inside `handleSubmit` and run in a debugger. Does it reach that code? If so, step through it line by line and check whether the variables are what you expect them to be.

Comment: thanks now its working. It was a problem with the security rules,. But now I have a new problem I dont know  how to create a Subcollection, I want to create a Subcollection in a User Document but I cant find a helpful answer in Firebase Documentation.  I have created the collection with          setDoc(doc(db, 'Users', auth.currentUser.uid), { Name: Name, Age: Age} )  what else do I need to add to this Code to create multiple subcollection files.